# store multi-line text in a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript

Ho to store multiline text in a javascript variable;

I am using PHP to assign value to javascript variable.

Please see a SAMPLE code below

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title> New Document </title>
 <?php

  $foo = " this is a 
               multiline statement";
 ?>

 <script> 
  bar = '<?php print $foo;?>';
  alert(bar);
 </script>
 </head>
  <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

I don't want to loose any white-space characters.How can this be done ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines/169035#169035): `<?php echo json_encode($foo); ?>` (PHP >= 5.2)

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, it's a bit annoying as you can't do it that way. You'll have to do it like this:

```
var str = [
    "Hello, this is a       \n"
    "multiline\n",
    "       string."
].join("");
```

Or, using a similar trick,

```
var str = [
    "Hello, this ",
    "     is a multiline ",
    "string separated by new lines ",
    " with each array index"
].join("\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\n` where you want to break the line.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title> New Document </title>
 <?php

  $foo = " this is a \n
               multiline statement";
 ?>

 <script> 
  bar = '<?php print $foo;?>';
  alert(bar);
 </script>
 </head>
  <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you want to output the text to browser, you will have to use `<br />` rather than `\n`.

More Info:

http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/special_characters.htm

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var JsString = "<?php 
echo str_replace(array("\n","\r","\r\n"),'','YOUR 
MULTI LINE 
STRING');?>";
```